# problem with frameset in Safari

Tags: html, safari

I am facing one problem with Frames . 
when i am trying to redirect one page from the another framset then its giving "Undefined" error .

Let say i have a frameset which i have divide into 2 horizontal frame, and again the lower the frame, i have again divide into 2 vertical frmaes and now i want to reload the right side of frame page from "left side " frmae , i mean i ll redirect the pages to Right side of Frame from left navigation.

while redirection i am getting exception as "Undefined".

Please help me out . this is creating lots of probelm for me.

thanks in Advance

Regards
Bijay

Comment: If you add your code into the question or a piece of sample code that showcases the issues you are having we would be better able to help you. Please do note that frames are one of the most hated things on the Internet because it makes direct linking to certain pages in emails almost impossible.

Answer (score 0):

You have to give your link or form a target attribute, that would hold the name of the frame you are trying to reload.